# Is it possible to join data from two different tables residing in two different DB's for AWS REDSHIFT.

Tags: join, amazon-redshift

As far as I have checked it is not a feature in REDSHIFT. Can we acheive it using DB Link!!

Please let me know if any of you have answers

Comment: workaround - on "DB 1" export your tables to s3 (unload) and then on "DB 2" set up external tables (redshift spectrum) pointing at those s3 tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. What @JonScott suggested is a really good option.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to run a cross-database query on Redshift. All tables or views for the query need to be within the same database.

Dblink is not a feature of Redshift so that is not applicable (although you CAN [use dblink from a RDS PostgreSQL or other PostgreSQL instance to connect to Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/join-amazon-redshift-and-amazon-rds-postgresql-with-dblink/)).

Comment: This is no longer true and cross-db queries are now supported by Redshift

Comment: @Oleksandr That is correct, this feature was added in 2021. Feel free to add a new answer with the updated information.